# Windows security keeps saying actions needed but doesn't specify which ones

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

The Windows Security icon sometimes says that actions are needed but when I click on it everything seems to be fine. **How do I find out what actions are needed?** The error goes away after a reboot but reappears after some time. This has been a very frustrating experience.

[Windows Security icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV5EO.png)
[Windows Security window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDlBu.png)

Comment: Windows Security does take a long time to load recommended actions. Try doing a Windows Defender Offline Scan so that malware is removed automatically.

Comment: I just did that and the icon once again has a check mark but I suspect that's because my PC got rebooted and not because any threat actually got removed.

Comment: You did Windows Defender Offline? That doesn't tell you if the threats were removed but usually it gets rid of them. You can check by doing a full scan. Let me know if it works so that I can add it as an answer and you'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Virus and threat protection Window and then work through all the items, particularly Threat Protection.  Threats will show up there and also in Quarantine. Work through threats and quarantine and you will find the threats.

[image]

Comment: Under **Virus & threat protection** in my screenshot it specifically says that no action is needed. Wouldn't it say otherwise if there were actually any action needed?

Comment: Look there under Protection history. The threat could have been cleared. I have none, but one one machine where there was threat you could see it here.  Restart your machine to see if the threat has gone

Comment: My protection history is empty. I'm still kind of puzzled why Windows Security would say that actions are needed but would not show me which ones but your answer seems to show the correct approach to solve this problem so I'll accept it.

Comment: You are very welcome. WD keeps evolving. I am using V2004  for my screens.